# Best way to say 'to move up' as in 'reschedule for an earlier point in time'

Tags: idiomaticity

Let's say I would like to reschedule an appointment, but to make it sooner, rather than later. I would like to know the most natural way a German speaker would say this. I'm familiar with "verschieben", but I'm afraid that carries the connotation that it will be scheduled for a *later* point in time.

As an American English speaker, I would say "to move it up." However, tranlating that into German doesn't give results that refer to time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A good choice would probably be [vorverlegen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/vorverlegen). "Verlegen" refers, among other meanings, to changing the position of something - in space and/or in time. Therefore,

> Die Besprechung nächste Woche wurde verlegt.

can refer to a spatial change (the meeting has been moved to another conference room) or to a temporal change (the meeting has been moved to another day in the week).

Combined with the prefix "vor-", it means something like "to change the position of something closer to the front" (however the front may be defined in the specific case). It *can* principally be used in a spatial context, but is typically used in a temporal one. So you could say something like

> Die Besprechung nächsten Donnerstag wurde auf Dienstag vorverlegt.

Comment: Also, and a bit more colloquial, "vorziehen".